# How to set http proxy in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I used this [Link](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/214230/how-do-you-configure-jenkins-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) for configuring http proxy in Jenkins, but after using printenv only those variables are set.

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

I expected that `http_proxy` and `HTTPS_PROXY` get also set.

I added following steps in my build stage to set those environment  variables but `http_proxy` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are not getting set.

```
   stage('build') {
        
        steps {
            echo "************ Before exporting ***************************"
            sh 'printenv | sort'
            sh "export http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:3128'"
            sh "export https_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:3128'"
            sh "export HTTP_PROXY='http://127.0.0.1:3128'"
            sh "export HTTPS_PROXY='http://127.0.0.1:3128'"
            echo "************ After exporting ***************************"
            sh 'printenv | sort'
            echo "**************************************************"
            sh './myScript'
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me to undrestand what is the problem and get `myScript` running, now it just fails because those variables are not correctly set?

Answer (score 0):

If proxy is only needed for this script, you can use the following:

```
withEnv(['HTTP_PROXY=http://${YOUR_PROXY}','HTTPS_PROXY=http://${YOUR_PROXY}']) {
    sh './myScript'    
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this but printing `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` gives always empty